# How do I find disconnected nodes on neo4j with Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, cypher

I am toying with neo4j and noticed that all Cypher queries need a starting point in the `START` clause. 
I was wondering how can I find all disconnected nodes using Cypher ?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all your nodes are indexed (e.g. via auto-indexing) you could use an index query as a start point and then find those nodes that have no outgoing relationships.

```
start n=node:node_auto_index("id:*")
match n-[r?]->m
where r is null
return n
```

Nowadays I would rather use:

```
start n=node:node_auto_index("id:*")
where not (n-->m)
return n
```

Comment: any way to index retroactively?

Comment: Yes, but you would have to create the desired indexes, then go through all the nodes and add them where appropriate. In the native java api, you'd use [GlobalGraphOperations.getAllNodes()](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/1.6.M02/apidocs/org/neo4j/tooling/GlobalGraphOperations.html#getAllNodes())

Comment: I'm afraid I can only use either REST or the webadmin... is there any hope?

Comment: Should be possible using the gremlin console. First enable the auto-index, then do the gremlin script. Don't have the syntax at hand but something, like g.V.each { it, idx -> it.id = idx } should be enough.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question well. The query would still match nodes that are connected to the graph by an inbound connection.

Comment: If you don't care about the type of node, direction of the relationships, or where the relationship goes, you can use a slight modification:  `START a=node(*) WHERE NOT ((a)--()) RETURN a;`

Answer (score 4):

With Neo4j v3.0+ I just use;

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT (n)--()
RETURN n
```

(or variations thereof). The query is reasonably fast.

Answer (score 2):

I use something like this, but only when I'm using spring-data-neo4j:

```
    start n = node:__types__(className="com.app.entity.Model")
    // match, where...
    return n
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can't. Graph global queries are not possible with todays Cypher.

Comment: they are now (Neo4j 1.7) with start n=node(*) match ... where ... return n

Comment: this answer gets downvoted eventually, but it was accurate at its time of posting as it seems