# NEO4J: Finding disconnected nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this sample data

[image: Sample data]

With the sample query

```
CREATE (a1:A {title: "a1"})
CREATE (a2:A {title: "a2"})
CREATE (a3:A {title: "a3"})

CREATE (b1:B {title: "b1"})
CREATE (b2:B {title: "b2"})

MATCH (a:A {title: "a1"}), (b:B {title: "b1"})
CREATE (a)-[r:LINKS]->(b)

MATCH (a:A), (b:B) return a,b
```

---

What I am trying to achieve:

1. Find all the node type A that are not connected to node type B (ans: a2, a3)
2. Find all the node type B that are not connected to node type A (ans: b2)
3. Both of this requirements are expected to be bi-directional, and have the same query template.

---

**Where I have reached**

Get all A not connected to B: gets me a2 and a3 as expected

```
MATCH path=(a:A)-[r]-(b:B)
WHERE (a)-[r]-(b)
WITH collect(a) as al
MATCH (c:A)
WHERE not c IN al
RETURN c
```

Get all disconnected B, I get both b1 and b2 which is incorrect, and printing "al" revealed that the list is empty

```
MATCH path=(b:B)-[r]-(a:A)
WHERE (b)-[r]-(a)
WITH collect(b) as al
MATCH (c:B)
WHERE not c IN al
RETURN c
```

some how

```
WHERE (b)-[r]-(a) **!=** WHERE (a)-[r]-(b)
```

even if I have the the direction as bi-directional (not mentioned)

If I change it to `WHERE (a)-[r]-(b)` in the second query then it works, but I want a generic bi-directional query.

Comment: Why not simply `MATCH (a:A)
WHERE NOT (a)--(:B)
RETURN a` and `MATCH (b:B)
WHERE NOT (b)--(:A)
RETURN b`?

Comment: yes it works thank you. I do understand this simpler query, but just for my understanding any idea what part of my query was incorrect? why was my where clause not working bi-directional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [the path pattern in `where`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/#query-where-patterns):

```
MATCH (a:A) WHERE NOT (a)-[:LINKS]-(:B)
RETURN a;

MATCH (b:B) WHERE NOT (b)-[:LINKS]-(:A)
RETURN b;
```

Or combine into one query:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a:A) WHERE NOT (a)-[:LINKS]-(:B)
WITH collect(a) AS aNodes
OPTIONAL MATCH (b:B) WHERE NOT (b)-[:LINKS]-(:A)
WITH aNodes, 
     collect(b) AS bNodes
RETURN aNodes, bNodes
```

**Update:** why the original query produces an incorrect result?

I think this is a bug. The problem is that when you use a variable for a relationship in `where`, the pattern implicitly uses the direction from left to right, even if it is not specified:

```
// Will return 0, but for test data should return 1
MATCH (b:B)-[r]-(a:A) WHERE (b)-[r]-(a)
RETURN COUNT(*);

// Will return 1
MATCH (b:B)-[r]-(a:A) WHERE (b)<-[r]-(a)
RETURN COUNT(*);

// Will return 1
MATCH (b:B)-[r]-(a:A) WHERE (b)--(a)
RETURN COUNT(*);

// Will return 1
MATCH (b:B)-[r]-(a:A) WHERE (a)-[r]-(b)
RETURN COUNT(*);
```

Comment: worked great, thanks. I do understand this simpler query, but just for my understanding any idea what part of my query was incorrect? why was my where clause not working bi-directional?

Comment: @SrinathGanesh Very interesting. I think this is a bug. Updated the answer.

Comment: Also for some reason **MATCH (a:A), (b:B) WHERE NOT (a)--(b) RETURN a**
 and 
**MATCH (a:A) WHERE NOT (a)--(:B) RETURN a** give different results

Comment: I have also started a new discussion specific to the anomaly you identified in the query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49814707/neo4j-cypher-query-relationship-direction-bug-in-where-clause

Comment: @SrinathGanesh `MATCH (a:A), (b:B) WHERE NOT (a)--(b) RETURN a` matches a A-B pair that are not directly connected. `MATCH (a:A) WHERE NOT (a)--(:B) RETURN a` matches a A that is not connected to any B. They are completely different in what they look for. That is way the results are different. Also, if you are just combining the results of 2 separate queries, you can just use UNION to get the results of both queries as one with no interference between them.

Comment: @Tezra you mean to say second query *where not a--b* will search at n levels?

Comment: @SrinathGanesh The first query will return A's that are connected to other B's as long as A isn't directly linked to THIS B. The second query will only return A if there is no link from it to ANY B. The key difference being that the first pattern only looks at one pair, the seconds checks against all pairs.

Comment: I'll go and check it in query for more clarity

Comment: @SrinathGanesh Another way to look at it is the Match gives you a set of rows (in the first query, a Cartesian product of A and B; the second just a list of A). The WHERE part then just filters those rows (First query, filter out rows where the A and B aren't directly connected; Second query, filter out rows where A has a connection to a B)). In the first query, by matching B, you bind the filter logic to one instance of B per row.

Comment: NEO4J has accepted this as a bug are will be fixing it in 3.1  https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/11542